# how to configure Multijob plugin to run 2 concurrent jobs in 1 phase in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I want to run three scripts on three different Linux machines at the same time.

I tried "Multi-job" plugin, but was not able to configure jobs to ssh over three different machines.

Thanks in advance for helping .

Comment: Have you managed to ssh in these machines using a Jenkins Freestyle job?